# BeautifulSoup findAll method is not finding all img tags?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm writing a web scraper script

```
picture = soup.find("div", {"id" : "thumbs-top"})
for link in picture.findAll("img"):
    counter += 1
```

This counter turns out to be 327 which is clearly not true. I was scraping this imgur gallery : http://imgur.com/a/akHsJ?gallery

Answer (score 2):

I am getting 575.

```
>>> import requests
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> r = requests.get('http://imgur.com/a/akHsJ?gallery')
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)
>>> picture = soup.find("div", {"id" : "thumbs-top"})
>>> links = picture.findAll("img")
>>> len(links)
575
```

**Edit:** In the comments we determined that the problem is fixed by trying a different html parser with BeautifulSoup. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16322862/beautiful-soup-findall-doent-find-them-all) question for more info.

```
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
```

Comment: I just typed exactly what you have into IDLE and it says 327. Does that mean my requests or BeautifulSoup is probably out of date?Edit: I just piped both and it says they';re both up to date

Comment: Can you try printing out r.text and trying to see what's going on? One thing I am noticing about the page in my browser is that you have to scroll down to load more images. Before I ran my code I thought that might be an issue, but it wasn't for me at least. I doubt there is any issue with your libraries.

Comment: If the html source looks OK, then try using some different parsers with BeautilfSoup, for example, try `soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')`

Comment: hm... I printed out r.text and the html source looked fine. I tried the html.parser and apparently that works since it printed out 575. Do you know why it didn't work for me but it did for you?Edit: Yea lxml parser (the default one) gives 327 while html.parser gives 575

Comment: Most likely the html is broken (most websites don't follow the html spec perfectly). It is strange that mine worked with the default parser, however. But see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16322862/beautiful-soup-findall-doent-find-them-all

Comment: @Imran you know what is interesting: I've tried all the available HTML parsers that bs4 supports - same result `575`. And with bs3 it is also `575`.