# BeautifulSoup find_all limited to 50 results?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get the results from a page using BeautifulSoup:

```
req_url = 'http://www.xscores.com/soccer/livescores/25-02'
request = requests.get(req_url)
content = request.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser")
scores = soup.find_all('tr', {'style': 'height:18px;'}, limit=None)
print(len(scores))
>50
```

I read this previous solution: [Beautiful Soup findAll doesn't find them all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16322862/beautiful-soup-findall-doent-find-them-all#16323809)
and I tried html.parser, lxml and html5lib, but none of them return more than 50 results. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `css-selector` query.

```
scores = soup.select('#scoretable > tr[style*="height:18px;"]')
print(len(scores))

>>>613
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this -

```
req_url = 'http://www.xscores.com/soccer/livescores/25-02'
request = requests.get(req_url)
html=request.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html5lib")
scoretable=soup.find('tbody',id='scoretable')
scores=scoretable.find_all('tr')
len(scores)
>617
```

Answer (score 2):

This line only finds rows **with** 'height:18px; style.

```
scores = soup.find_all('tr', {'style': 'height:18px;'}, limit=None)
```

If you look at the page source and search for `"height:18px;"` you'll see 50 matches. But if you search for `height:18px;` without the quotes you'll see 613 matches.

You need to edit that line to find rows that **has** height:18px; style (and other values).
You can pass a regex as style argument according to [documentations](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#the-keyword-arguments), maybe something like this:

```
soup.find_all('tr', style = re.compile('height:18px'), limit=None)
```