# Python web scraping unable to find all the tags in a webpage

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape a particular web page.But I'm unable to find all the paragraph tags in it.

I've gone through the below question

[Beautiful Soup findAll doen't find them all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16322862/beautiful-soup-findall-doent-find-them-all) , but this doesn't seem to solve the issue.

It's a continuously refreshing dynamic web page that loads additional content if I click the 'Load More Commentary' button at the bottom of the page.

Code :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

r = requests.get("http://www.cricbuzz.com/live-cricket-scores/18127")
data = r.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
p = soup.find_all('p')

len(p)
```

> 10

```
print(p[9])
```

> Boult to Hardik Pandya, **FOUR**, **that is probably the blunder which will cost KKR the match**. It shouldn't have been any more than a single. A low full toss which Hardik can't find any elevation with. 
>   He smacks it down to long-on, where Surya attacks the ball nicely but he misfields and the ball sneaks through

Is there anyway I will be able to scrape the entire commentary data from this web page  ?

Comment: `requests.get()` does not retrieve dynamic content. You shall use other means of scraping, e.g., Selenium.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For getting all comments you can use site API: `http://push.cricbuzz.com/match-api/18127/commentary-full.json`. It returns all data in json format which you can easy parse and extract what you need:

```
import requests

r = requests.get('http://push.cricbuzz.com/match-api/18127/commentary-full.json').json() 

all_comments = r['comm_lines']

# print first 10 comments
for comment in all_comments[:10]:
    if 'comm' in comment:
        print(comment['comm'])
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are getting there is the paragraph p[9] (p-tag) I suppose, you need to put the printing statement in a loop to be able to print all the paragraphs. Something like this:

```
body = soup.body
for p in body.find_all('p')
    print(p.text)
```

Comment: I understand that I need to use a loop if I were to print all the paragraphs. But the find_all itself is returning only 10 tags whereas there are a lot more in the page.

Comment: @AdarshHV I modified the code to give you only the text in the p-tags and for your question on why only those 10 tags I thing those are the only active p-tags on the page.