# Scrape URLs using BeautifulSoup in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, urllib

I tried this code but the list with the URLs stays empty. No error massage, nothing.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
import re

req = Request('https://www.metacritic.com/browse/movies/genre/date?page=0', headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
html_page = urlopen(req).read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page, features="xml")
links = []
for link in soup.findAll('a', attrs={'href': re.compile("^https://www.metacritic.com/movie/")}):
    links.append(link.get('href'))

print(links)
```

I want to scrape all the URLs that start with "https://www.metacritic.com/movie/" that are found in the given URL "https://www.metacritic.com/browse/movies/genre/date?page=0".

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First you should use the standard library "html.parser" instead of "xml" for parsing the page content. It deals better with broken html (see [Beautiful Soup findAll doesn't find them all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16322862/beautiful-soup-findall-doesnt-find-them-all))

Then take a look at the source code of the page you are parsing. The elements you want to find look like this: `<a href="/movie/woman-at-war">`

So change your code like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
import re

req = Request('https://www.metacritic.com/browse/movies/genre/date?page=0', headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
html_page = urlopen(req).read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page, 'html.parser')
links = []
for link in soup.findAll('a', attrs={'href': re.compile("^/movie/")}):
    links.append(link.get('href'))

print(links)
```

Comment: Many thanks. One additional question, because it seems that you are good at regex: How can I omit all URLs that are not like "/movie/movie-name" e.g. "/movie/movie-name/trailers". I tried "re.compile("^/movie/.+[^\/]")" but he keeps all the unwanted URLs.

Comment: You could use a regex like "^/movie/([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+$" to match links only containing letters, numbers and minuses after "/movie/"

Comment: `if '/trailers/' not in link.get('href'):
        links.append(link.get('href'))`

Answer (score 2):

Your code is sound.

The list stays empty because there aren't any URLs on that page matching that pattern. Try `re.compile("^/movie/")` instead.

Comment: @leiropi is right, `features="xml"` is also giving you problems. `soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page, 'lxml')` does give the right results though.