# Scraping data with multiple same class name using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm practicing scraping using a real-estate website, and I want to **scrape** all addresses for recent sales. For example, the part of the website HTML looks like this:
url = https://www.compass.com/agents/irene-vuong/

```
<div class="profile-active-listings" role="tabpanel" id="active-listings-sales">
    <div class="card-content">
      <a class="card-title" href="/listing" data-tn="label-address"> 111 East 35th </a>
                                            ........
<div class="textIntent-headline1"> Recent Sales</div>
    <div class="card-content">
      <a class="card-title" href="/morelisting" data-tn="label-address"> East 4th </a>
```

And I'm trying to get access to all address, using below code:

```
for i in range(0, 30):
    h = soup.findAll('a', {'class':'card-title'})[i]
    print(h)
```

However, I get an error of:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I get the first few addresses, but only right before "Recent Sales".
It's only getting addresses on the first part but not the entire website.
How do I get all addresses?

Comment: Could you share the actual page you're trying to scrape?

Comment: @ZacharyBlackwood I have just added!

Comment: It looks like you might be using the wrong `class`. There are currently 12 items on that page with the class `uc-listingCart-title`, not `card-title`. If you loop through those as suggested by @user2263572 (as opposed to hard-coding the `30`), that should give you all the items you're looking for.

Comment: @ZacharyBlackwood Hi, I tried the suggestion but it still only gets part of it and not all.... :-(

Comment: Ah. Looks like the extra items are being added dynamically on the front-end. This answer might be helpful for getting the page contents after javascript has added the items. https://stackoverflow.com/a/26440563/5031672

Answer (score 0):

The findAll method returns a list of all elements that match your search criteria.

In your case, it returns a list of length 2.

you are then iterating through 0-29 and looking for those indexes on your list of length2.

Hence your error.

Your code should read something more like:

```
for x in soup.findAll('a', {'class':'card-title'}):
  print(x)
```

Comment: Above response answers your original question.  This answers your current questions.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16322862/beautiful-soup-findall-doesnt-find-them-all

Comment: Hi I'm not sure how the post is relevant to my questions... I'm using 'html.parser' in my code. Can you please explain? It will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your question "Scraping data with multiple same class name using BeautifulSoup" and your issue is "findall not finding everything it should". I linked the question "Beautiful Soup findAll doesn't find them all".  I think it's relevant.  Either the link explains your issue, or you aren't using correct css selectors.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think the post is helpful :-( I think my problem is different than the one in the post.