# BeautifulSoup is not findign all the tags

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, tags

Im learning how to scrape the web with BeautifulSoup in python 3.8 and i have run into a issue i cant find the solution.

Im trying to get the brands of each product from this page:

https://www.linio.com.mx/c/computacion/pc-portatil

There are 68 products and im only getting 60, i know for sure my script is not grabbing the first and the last product which are ASUS A540 and Lenovo Ideapad L340 respectively.

This is my script

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup


my_url = 'https://www.linio.com.mx/c/computacion/pc-portatil'



uClient = urlopen(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()


soup_page = soup(page_html, 'html.parser')

containers = soup_page.find(id="catalogue-product-container").findAll(True, recursive=False)


for container in containers:


    try:
        print(container.a.find(itemprop="brand")["content"])

    except TypeError:
        pass
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that the HTML parser is not perfect and there are people facing similar problem to yours - [Beautiful Soup findAll doesn't find them all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16322862/beautiful-soup-findall-doesnt-find-them-all).

I ran your code and I get the same problem. The bug already happens at the 'find' and 'findAll' method already -- Based on the first page, it seems that **only sponsored products are not extracted** for some unknown reason to me.

Have you tried Selenium instead? In my experience, Selenium gives less problem for me and saved me so much time as compared to other web scraping libraries. But that's just my opinion. :)